# BeautifulSoup link attribute in Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, findall

I was exploring BeautifulSoup by referencing Ryan Mitchell's "Web Scraping with Python".

There are sample codes that explain scraping article links from wikipedia. I omitted import codes for brevity. The code is:

```
html = urlopen("http://en.wikipedia.org")
bsObj = BeautifulSoup(html)

for link in bsObj.findAll("a", href = re.compile("^(/wiki/)((?!:).)*$")):
     if 'href' in link.attrs:
          print(link.attrs['href'])
```

I was confused why the code needs to include the if statement:

```
if 'href' in link.attrs:
```

Doesn't the findAll function return all anchor tags that have the specified href? Therefore, wouldn't it be okay to assume that all the 'link' will have 'href' as attributes?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: what is the exact error you're getting? did you tried to print the error on your terminal?

Comment: You can't be sure that the `a` tag has a link (href attribut). That's what the test (`if 'href' in link.attrs:...`) is for. First test if the `href` is among the attributes, then print the value if there is one.

Answer (score 0):

your line of thoughts is valid, however try experimenting by maybe adding an else statement and printing link.attrs in the else statement, see if any of the links don't have an href attribute, which should never be the case, but you never know, good luck.

Answer (score -1):

because return from this line

```
for link in bsObj.findAll("a", href = re.compile("^(/wiki/)((?!:).)*$")):
```

not only 'href' but any other attribute

so this line  if 'href' in link.attrs: for make sure you get attribut 'href' only